# How to prevent QListView from acquiring all icons at startup?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using a `QListView` with a custom model derived from `QStringListModel` to display a large series of images, or, to be more specific, data curves. I used to use `QListWidget`, but I have so many of them that setting the icons (quite high res) for all of the items just takes all the memory, and cause a very long startup time. I thought that switching to `QListView` with a custom model would solve the problem (and it does solve the memory problem), but not the long startup time, as all the icons are requested by `QListView` at startup (I see that by just writing the names on the terminal).

Do you have any way to work around this ? The best I can think of for now is to have a thumbnailer thread that trashes its queue when it gets too large, but that seems very cumbersome.

Comment: If you use `QListView` (or other item views) you don't need to have all items at a time, but only those that should be visible on the screen. You just need to implement this concept in your custom model and it will solve your performance issues.

Comment: @vahancho Hmmm. It completely defeats the purpose of the separation between model and view. The model has no way of knowing which items are visible at a given time. Have you ever tried what you suggest ?

Comment: If you have an implementation sketch, please post it as an answer, I'll be glad to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, in my case, it is rather simple:

```
list->setUniformItemSizes(true);
```

This way, the `QListView` doesn't have to look at all icons to know their size.